# How to allow a user to upload images in an album of a page via facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a facebook app thats published in a tab of a commercial-page. Plus, i created an album on that page for a contest where people should be able to upload images in. 
People should the be able to "like" those images. The one with the most likes is the winner.

I already created the app, my problem is that I dont know how to set the scope correctly to allow those users uploading in the pages album, or how to allow the album to receive images from those users.

The action URL in the FORM-TAG looks like this:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/{THE_ALBUM_ID}/photos?access_token=" .$access_token;
```

The response is alsways

```
{ "error": {
    "message": "(#120) Invalid album id",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 120
    }
}
```

Im sure its a scope/permission problem - any hints?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Fab

Comment: well apparently the album ID is wrong

Comment: no - the album ID is definately correct, i checked that a few times. I think it has to do with the permission that the user isnt allowed to upload in the album.

Comment: what do you mean you checked it? have you tried it like this `https://graph.facebook.com/{THE_ALBUM_ID}` or like this `https://www.facebook.com/{THE_ALBUM_ID}`?!

Comment: i checked it like this: https://www.facebook.com/{THE_ALBUM_ID}
Also i see the ALBUM_ID when hovering over the link to the album ...

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have written

**$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);**

and permission is 
**user_photos**

Comment: I already did it like this in my app, since i already researched before posting here:

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'fileUpload' => true,
      'cookie' => true
    ));
 
 $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

But didnt work

Comment: hope u didnt got me wrong:
i want the user to upload an image over the app to MY album, not his ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way with the current API to allow a user of an application to upload to a specific page's album.  They will always, with one exception, go into one album. The exception is if you're uploading with the page access token (or was it if uploading as the admin of the page...doesn't really matter to the answer of your question), then they will go into a different album.